# Tag for the field of fractions

Tags: support, tagging

I wanted to edit in the [fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fractions) tag a related / suggested alternate tag for the field of fractions of a ring (integral domain). But to my surprise I can't find a tag for the field of fractions!

What's the appropriate tag for the field of fractions?

Comment: If you wanted it to be a synonym, but it doesn't exist, then perhaps you should let it be.  We use the synonym mechanism to reduce tag space.

Comment: I would use one of *abstract-algebra*, *integral-domain*, *field-theory*, *ring-theory*. I am not sure that we need a separate tage for fields of fractions. I am not decidedly against it either. I just have a hard time seeing someone specialize on field of fractions, or favoriting that tag. Mind you, field of fraction is also a special case of a localization of a commutative ring, so *commutative-algebra* is also a possibility.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  [tag:localization] exists

Comment: OK thanks @JyrkiLahtonen.

Comment: I think the [tag:fractions] tag itself is pretty poor.

Comment: Which makes your effort to suggest alternative (perhaps more cogent) tags worthwhile in editing the Wiki.